# Can I create & run test cases for smart contract without truffle?How?

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs

does truffle is  necessary for smart contract testing?
Is there any alternative way, so that we can perform smart contract testing without truffle?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Truffle is not necessary.
You can write your own compile.js and Contract.test.js files to do the testing using mocha. you will have to install the solc and ganache-cli node modules for this.

Explanation in detail
This will be your compile file:

```js
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const solc = require("solc");

//change the contractFileName
const path = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", contractFileName);
const source = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8");

/*
instead of 'Contract' it will be the name of the contract 
class you wrote in the solidity file. The colon is
required
*/ 
module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[":Contract"];
```

This will be your test file:

```js
const assert = require("assert");
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const { interface, bytecode } = require("../compile");

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

beforeEach(async()=>{
//your before each logic goes here
});

describe(ContractName, ()=>{
//your it blocks go here
});
```

Comment: can you please explain this with example.

Comment: i have edited the answer to include a basic explanation of compiling and testing without truffle

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: You can use mocha. Install mocha in your workspace and simply run the mocha command. Make sure the test file is in the directory test